# Calling javascript object value gives me 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, google-maps

I'm working on a google map application and I want some markers to load from a db and display them on a map. So I created an array and defined an object like this.

```
function shop_data(name,latitude,longitude,type)
    {
    this.name=name;
    this.latitude=latitude;
    this.longitude=longitude;
    this.type=type;
    }
```

Then I added some data retrieved from an ajax request to an array of 'shop_data' objects. The array is defined as 'all_shops'.

```
var i=0;
for(var o in data){
var name = data[o].name;
    var type = data[o].type;
var lat = data[o].lat;
var lng = data[o].lng;

all_shops[i]=new shop_data(name,lat,lng,type);
i++
}
```

Then when i call 'all_shops[i].name', it gives me the name as it is. But when I call 'all_shops[i].lat' or 'all_shops[i].lng' it gives me 'undefined'. I tried parsing the lat,lng too. Here lat, lng are double variables in MySQL database. 
I can get the lat,lng values without a problem from the received ajax data by calling, just name,type,lat,lng. But things go wrong when i put them all in an array and , call them from the array. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You defined latitude as "latitude" so of course that accessing it as "lat" will return undefined.

Comment: Oh no.... Am I such an idiot.... Anyway thanks bellpeace. I got it. Thanks a lot for taking your time for answering my foolish question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your `latitude` or `longitude` from `all_shops[i]` not `lat` or `lng`
as you have your `shop_data` function definition like this

```
function shop_data(name,latitude,longitude,type)
{
   this.name=name;
   this.latitude=latitude;
   this.longitude=longitude;
   this.type=type;
}
```

or if want to use `lat` or `lng` then change `shop_data` function definition like

```
function shop_data(name,latitude,longitude,type)
{
   this.name=name;
   this.lat=latitude;
   this.lng=longitude;
   this.type=type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yograj, I got it. It's so embarrasing. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Change from

```
this.latitude=latitude;
this.longitude=longitude;
```

to

```
this.lat=latitude;
this.lng=longitude;
```

You have a simple copy/paste error.

Answer (score 1):

Changing variable names to match and a little cleanup gives:

```
function shop_data(name,latitude,longitude,type){
    this.name=name;
    this.lat=latitude;
    this.lng=longitude;
    this.type=type;
}
```

and:

```
var i=0;
for(var o in data){
    var name = data[o].name;
    var type = data[o].type;
    var lat = data[o].lat;
    var lng = data[o].lng;

    all_shops[i]=new shop_data(name,lat,lng,type);
    i++
}
```